# How to concatenate a conditional field and remove the same value

Tags: sql, concatenation, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a column with a case statement, then concatenate the column. Here is an example code.

```
WITH base AS (
SELECT ID, Date, Action, case when (Date is null then Action || '**' else Action End) Action_with_no_date
FROM <Table_Name>
)
SELECT ID, "array_join"("array_agg"(DISTINCT Action_with_no_date), ', ') Action_with_no_date
FROM base
GROUP BY ID;
```

Basically, the `Action_with_no_date` will display the concatenation of values in `Action` with `'**'` string added to the values where `Date` is null for each `ID`

After I did this, I found an edge case.

If there is the same `Action` (i.e. `play`) taken for one `ID`, and if one action has `date` and the other one doesn't, then the output will have one `play` and one `play**` for the `ID`

However, I want this to display just one `play` with **.
Below is the example data for `ID = 1`

```
ID Date  Action
1  1/2/22 read
1  1/3/22 play
1  NULL   play
```

and expected result for the `ID`

```
ID Action_with_no_date
1  read, play**
```

How should I handle this?

Comment: Can you please share some example data and expected results?

Comment: edited with sample data and expected results. Sorry I am not sure how to provide the sample data in Presto

Comment: Hi there Yun. The edit from @KenWhite was correct - where a topic is added at the start or the end of the title to form a home-made "tag", we remove them. This is what the tagging system is for - please use that instead. Thanks!

Comment: There is a canonical reference for [the preference to not add tags into titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often) (or why they are removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate `**` suffix if there is any row with null per id and action using analytic max() with case expression. Then concatenate suffix with action.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, '1/2/22', 'read'),
        (1, '1/3/22', 'play'),
        (1, NULL, 'play')
) AS t (id, date, action)
)

select id, array_join(array_agg(DISTINCT action||suffix), ', ')
from
(
select id, date, action,
       max(case when date is null then '**' else '' end) over(partition by id, action) as suffix
  from mytable
)s
group by id
```

Result:

```
1   play**, read
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much.